# OpenGL - glVertex replaces drawn points?

Tags: opengl, replace

In the following OpenGL code, what happens?

```
glNormal3f( nx1, ny1, nz1 )
glVertex3f( x1,y1,z1 )
glNormal3f( nx2, ny2, nz2 ) //different Normal
glVertex3f( x1,y1,z1 )      //same vector
```

In words:
I have a point with a normal, If I create the point again with another normal, the point changes his old normal vector, or ignores the last call?

This question came about when I was trying to render a sphere with lighting in a smoother way
using the normals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will simply draw both in exactly the same location. There is no magic behind the scenes where points are "recognized" as being in the same location, updating normals and such.

Comment: what about the normals? imagen two triangles that share a side in common... if i reassign the normals to points, does the triangle face change it's normal when it comes to lighting??

Comment: It depends a bit on how you have defined things. What does your code look like surrounding these vertices and normals? You can have "per vertex" normals which are a normalized average of the normals of the faces connected to this vertex to obtain smooth shading. Or just the face normals (perhaps written as separate normals per vertex) to have flat shaded triangles. In the latter case you might get what you show in your code. The same vertex appearing multiple times with multiple normals.

Comment: ok. What do you mean by "per vertex"  normals? How is that smooth shading implemented?

Comment: This gives as good an explanation as I can give: http://www.lighthouse3d.com/opengl/terrain/index.php3?normals ;)

Comment: ok! thanks a lot. I understand.  In my case, I was drawing a sphere...I was trying to calculate the sum of surrounding normals, but i wasn't necessary. I assigned each vertex a normal equal to the radius normalized and it worked.  In order for this smoothing to occur, openGl needs some enable() option, or is it built in ?

Comment: you answered my main question,. Thank you!! I love SO.

Answer (score 1):

`glNormal3f()` just sets the current normal, which will stay that way until the next `glNormal3f()` call.

Each `glVertex3f()` copies off the current normal, color, and texture coordinates and submits a complete vertex to GL command queue.